# I'M GETTING TypeError: records.map is not a function in my react app

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: records.map is not a function FROM MY Records.js file

Please what am I doing wrong in my code?

Here's my `app.js`:

```
const App = () => {
  const [records, setRecords] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRecords = async () => {
        setLoading(true)
        const res = await fetch('http://api.enye.tech/v1/challenge/records')
        const data  = await res.json();
        setRecords(data)
        setLoading(false)
      } 
     fetchRecords()
     // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []) 

  console.log(records);
  
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <SearchBar />
        <div className='container'>
          <h2>Records Firstnames</h2>
          <Records loading={loading} records={records} />
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
```

I'm rendering the fetched data from this `Records.js` file:

```
const Records = ({ records, loading }) => {
if(loading) {
    return <Preloader />
}
    return <ul className='collection mb-4'>
             {records && records.map(record => (
                <li key={record.id} className='collection-item'>
                    {record.FirstName}
                    {record.LastName}
                </li>
             ))}

            </ul>
```

}

This is the API I'm fetching from:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to the array portion of the api reponse (records), otherwise the data wil be an object ({}) which you cannot use .map on. the data.records.profiles will be an array ([]) and that will work with a .map function.

change you code to

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRecords = async () => {
        setLoading(true)
        const res = await fetch('http://api.enye.tech/v1/challenge/records')
        const data  = await res.json();
        setRecords(data.records.profiles)
        setLoading(false)
      } 
     fetchRecords()
     // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [])
```

also check that the records are not loading

```
 {!loading ? <Records records={records} /> : <></>}
```

You might also want to change the state name to 'profiles' and not records because you are only using the profiles portion on the reponse

Comment: when i add the 'profiles' to the data.profiles, i get an undefined and still the error of map undefined

Comment: do i need to change the props I'm passing to Records component? if yes, what do I change?

Comment: @Bruno I updated the code, tested it myself and it works

Comment: With pleasure, feel free to mark the comment as correct and upvote it, for other people that might have the same problems

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, your `records` is just an object so you can't iterate using map - you have to iterate over the profiles array.

change

`setRecords(data)`

to

`setRecords(data.records.profiles)`

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: i have tried it... no difference. it says undefined when I console.log it

Comment: after changing to data.profiles, do i need to change the props I'm passing to Records component? if yes, what do I change?